# How do you access a DocumentReference object stored in Firestore from a Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my `Firestore` database I store `DocumentReferences` to users so that I am always using up-to-date user data such as username, profile pictures, and auth tokens.

I am also implementing `Cloud Functions` to listen for database triggers so that I can send notifications to those specific users about activity related to their posts.

This is where I run into trouble, because I do not know how to use the stored reference object properly inside the `Node.js` function when I access it like all other database information.

**The following is my function code:**

```
exports.countNameChanges = functions.firestore
.document('posts/{postId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  // Retrieve the current and previous value
  const data = change.after.data();
  const previousData = change.before.data();
  var registrationToken = '';

  var notification = '';
  var postTitle = data.statement;
  var userRef = data.userRef; //This is my `DocumentReference` object

  if (data.interactionCount > previousData.interactionCount && data.postTypeId == 2131165321) notification = 'You recieved a new comment!';
  if (data.interactionCount > previousData.interactionCount && data.postTypeId == 2131165335) notification = 'You recieved a new vote!';
  if (data.likes > previousData.likes) notification = 'You have a new post like!' ;
  if (data.dislikes > previousData.dislikes) notification = 'You have a new post dislike!' ;

  admin.firestore()
        .doc(userRef) //This is my `DocumentReference` object
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
            registrationToken = doc.data().token;

            var payload = {
               data: {
                  title: postTitle,
                  body: notification
               },
               token: registrationToken
            };

            admin.messaging().send(payload)
            .then((response) => {
               console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
               })
            .catch((error) => {
               console.log('Error sending message:', error);
               })
        });

   });

});
```

**My Function Log**

[image]

I would assume that the `DocumentReference` object would be easy to work with
inside a `Cloud Function` since the object is supported for direct storage into `Firestore`, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If `userRef` is a DocumentReference type object, then just call `get()` on it directly.  Don't pass it to `doc()`.  You're only supposed to pass string type objects to `doc()`.

```
userRef.get().then(...)
```

Comment: I had already tried this, except I included the `admin` prefix. I have since simply replaced the `DocumentReference` object with a string of the specific document in `Firestore` and refactored my app to simply build the reference from that.

Comment: What do you mean "I included the admin prefix"?  None of what you're saying here makes sense to me.

Comment: I just meant I did what you suggested before asking and was unsuccessful.